# Laplace's Rule of Succession and Bessel's Correction

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, philosophy

Are applying [Laplace's Rule of Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) to estimate a probability distribution from samples and applying [Bessel's Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) (in reverse, perhaps) to estimate population statistics from sample statistics ultimately mathematically the same action?

Also, my understanding is that Laplace's Rule of Succession is based on blending sample data with the proportions of a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution).  Is the idea ultimately grounded in a philosophically arbitrary application of the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference)?  Is there any argument for why we should assume the quantities we apply Laplace's Rule of Succession to are *a priori* uniform?

Comment: Can you show the math terms you are referring to?

Comment: Laplace's Rule of Succession as a binomial parameter estimator in the $\frac{s+1}{n+2}$ is what you get from starting with a prior distribution of $\text{Beta}(1,1)$ to get a posterior distribution  $\text{Beta}(s+1,n-s+1)$, and then minimise the expected squared loss with a point estimate.  It is a biased estimator of the parameter and $\frac{s}{n}$ would be an unbiased estimator.  There is no similar Bayesian argument for Bessel's correction, which instead is an unbiased estimator of the variance.  So I would not describe them as the same action.